# Conditional Proc in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Proc is used in our code for selecting records. Here is an example:

```
Proc.new { models.where('payment_requestx_payment_requests.paid = ?',  params[:paid_s] == 'true')}
```

We are looking for a way to run this `Proc` if a simple condition is met. Otherwise skip the `Proc` if condition returns false. Something like:

```
Proc.new { models.where('payment_requestx_payment_requests.paid = ?',  params[:paid_s] == 'true') if params[:condition] == 'true' }
```

The condition has to be inside the `Proc`. Is this something doable in ruby/rails?

Comment: What would the proc return if the condition was false?

Comment: The example you posted is valid ruby - what aspect of it doesn't work?

Comment: `Frederick`, I did not try it. I did not find similar example online and not sure if `Proc` will take `if`. Will fire up.

Comment: `mu is too short`, force to skip the whole `Proc` if condition is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the setup you are dealing with(sort of):

```
p = Proc.new { [{a:1}, {b:2}] }
p.call
 => [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

with an if statement:

```
p = Proc.new { [{a:1},{b:2}] if false }
p.call
 => nil
```

Active record returns an empty array if no records satisfy the where condition so I would assume that is what you need to supply:

```
p = Proc.new { false ? [{a:1},{b:2}] : [] }
p.call
 => []
```

Or in your case:

```
Proc.new { params[:condition] == 'true' ? models.where('payment_requestx_payment_requests.paid = ?',  params[:paid_s] == 'true') : [] }
```

Caveat Emptor.

Comment: Model.none - is more kosher way to return an empty ActiveRecord

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using ternary operator could help?

```
p = Proc.new {condition ? puts('condition is true!') : puts('condition is false!')}
condition = false
p.call
>> condition is false!
condition = true
p.call
>> condition is true!
```